# Asp.net core 3.0 - static files don't load

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I just deployed a new asp.net core 3.0 project, but it seems most of the files are not loading, e.g. the boostrap, css files and lots of images. (AS the website is all over the place)

I looked through the project (root solution) and included them in my project. (Deleted the entire solution online and re-published it again and again ) even restarted VS.

here is my statup.cs

```
 app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot"))
           ,
        RequestPath = new PathString("/wwwroot")
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
```

But it did not change the problem

Here is a browser tools. Any advise ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have missed this in your program.cs
try adding like this

```
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

like

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel()
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.Build();

host.Run();
```

and in startup.configure use UseDirectoryBrowser as

```
app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/MyImages")//this is the folder under 
   images 
});
```

And add  AddDirectoryBrowser extension method in Startup.ConfigureServices as

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddDirectoryBrowser();
}
```

and add like this in your startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/MyImages")
});

app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\images")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/MyImages")
});
}
```

and also add like this in your startup.configure as

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
  app.UseDefaultFiles();
  app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am using asp.net core 3.1, we can configure static file option by using the following code.In this code we have the file folder named "myfiles", in wwwroot static resource directory,  I just want to access this folder by using another name "files" . For more asp.net core tutorial visit my blog website https://www.yogeshdotnet.com

In Asp.Net Core 3.1

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(

    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),  @"wwwroot\myfiles")),
            RequestPath = new PathString("/files")
        });
```

In Asp.Net Core 2.1

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider (
                
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "myfile")), RequestPath =new PathString("/files")
        });
```